# A doubt about the way to understand the area between two curves through integration

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, area

I am rather confused on how to proceed with the calculation of the black-coloured area in the following picture:

[image]

Note: this is a "random" figure from a book which has nothing to do with my actual problem. I was however intrigued in trying to understand how to proceed. I know that in general those "kind" of areas are found through

$$A = \int_a^b \vert f(x)- g(x)\vert\ \text{d}x$$

Where $a, b$ are the intersection between the curves, so here it's like $a = -1$ and $b = 3$.

However if I compute $$\int_{-1}^0 f(x)-g(x)\ \text{d}x$$ I can see it's wrong for

$$\int_{-1}^0 f(x)\ \text{d}x$$

would be the area under the concave parabola from $-1$ and $3$, whereas

$$\int_{-1}^0 g(x)\ \text{d}x$$

is the area under the green curve. Their difference is actually the black region + the are under the parabola from an unknown point (negative) on x-axis and $3$.

It seems like a very trivial question, but I'm rather stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: From that area you have to subtract the are of the parabolic segment  on top of the x-axis. To do it, you need the x-coordinate of the intersection point of the parabola with the x-axis.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I would like to understand the logic of the integration for that shaded area, which I am missing. I need to understand this part. Isn't there a simpler way for this? 

Also, I think I wrote a nonsense: the integration of $g(x)$, the green one, gives me the area under that curve from $-1$ to $3$ but as you can see there will be a small amount of area remaining

Comment: $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is the (vertical) distance between two fixed curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$. To the left of some number $c$ between $0$ and $-1$, this distance is $|f-g|=|\text{parabola}-\text{log curve}|$. For all other $x$ between $c$ and $3$, the distance is $|0-g(x)|$. Then you need two integrals to get the area. You can work around this and only require one integral with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the comment of Mauro ALLEGRANZA, in order to solve the problem you have to first determine the value of $x$ such that $-1 < x < 3$ and $f(x) = 0.$

That is, you first have to determine the intersection point of the function $f(x)$ with the $x$ axis.  Denote this point as $c$.

Then, in order to compute the desired area, you have to split the region into two sections.

For $-1 \leq x \leq c$, the desired computation is $f(x) - g(x)$. 
That is, for any $x$ such that $-1 \leq x \leq c$, the **pertinent** *mythical* thin strip, of infinitesimally small width $~dx~$ has height $f(x) - g(x).$

For $c \leq x \leq 3$, the desired computation is $- g(x).$ 
That is, for any $x$ such that $c \leq x \leq 3$, the **pertinent** *mythical* thin strip, of infinitesimally small width $~dx~$ has height
$- g(x).$

Therefore, once the value of $c$ (i.e. the intersection point) is determined, the area is computed as

$$\int_{-1}^c [f(x) - g(x)] ~dx + \int_c^3 -g(x) ~dx.$$

Comment: I have troubles in understanding why $-g(x)$

Comment: Ok I got it, because it's like $x$ axis minus $g(x)$, under that portion. Thank you!

Comment: @Numb3rs Because $g(x)$ in and of itself is a function that takes on negative values, in the region $-1 \leq x \leq 3.$  First consider the 2nd region, given by $c \leq x \leq 3.$  The area is to be expressed as a **positive** amount.  If (instead) you compute $$\int_c^3 g(x) ~dx,$$ you will end up with a **negative** area.

Comment: @Numb3rs Yes, you nailed it.  It is because you want to compute the area between the $x$-axis and $g(x)$ for $c \leq x \leq 3.$

Comment: Thank you, I'm happy I got the meaning! :D